# Правильно ли помещать логику ввода данных с консоли в конструктор?

Tags: java

Задание: "Реализовать программу учета среднесуточной температуры на протяжении месяца. Ввод данных реализовать с консоли."
Что правильнее:

1. Поместить в конструктор по умолчанию логику ввода данных с консоли со всеми валидациями?
2. Создать отдельный метод для ввода данных, затем создавать объект класса, и к нему применять этот метод?

У меня сейчас вот так в конструкторе:

```
public TemperatureRecords() {
    System.out.println("Введите название месяца:");
    setMonth(input.nextLine().toLowerCase());
    while (getDaysAmount()!=0) {
        System.out.printf("Введите температуру %d числа:%n", temp);

        try {
            setTemperature(input.nextInt());
            setDaysAmount(getDaysAmount()-1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка!");
            input.skip(".*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По моему помещать такое в конструктор не надо. Надо всё это делать в отдельно методе, и лучше сделать два класса, один хранит данные, которые юзер ввел и другой, который запрашивает данные, валидирует их и только после этого запихивает в класс с данными.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определённо, нет. То, как это реализовано у вас - явно неправильно. В вашем случае конструктор класса и сам класс зависят от консольного ввода. Вообще зависимости между классами - вещь не очень хорошая, а зависимости настолько явные и того хуже. 
В данном случае мы имеем вот какую проблему: ваш класс не может работать без консоли, хотя не имеет к ней ни малейшего отношения. Представьте, что вам понадобилось использовать этот класс в каком-то другом приложении, где взаимодействие с пользователем происходит не через консоль, а каким-то другим способом (страница в браузере, форма десктопного приложения или как-то ещё). Вы не сможете корректно создать экземпляр вашего класса, и конструктор потребуется переписывать (или добавлять ещё один) чтобы он мог принимать данные не из консоли. 
Это говорит о том, что конструктор должен принимать необходимые данные в качестве параметров, класс можно будет безболезненно использовать о куда угодно. Как-то так:

```
public TemperatureRecords(String month, int[] temperatureData) {        
    setMonth(month);
    for(int value : temperatureData) {
        setTemperature(value);
        setDaysAmount(getDaysAmount()-1);           
    }         
}
```

Дело даже не в том, что конструктор стал вдвое короче (вырезанный из него код все равно должен будет использоваться, только в другом месте), а в том, что он во-первых, стал проще, а в-вторых, и в-главных, он теперь получает только те данные, которые ему нужны, знать ничего не знает ни о каких классах, которые не имеют к нему отношения и, следовательно, может быть вызван откуда угодно.

Логику же получения данных от пользователя и их валидацию правильнее будет возложить на другой код, разделив тем самым логику вашего класса и логику получения для него данных (да-да, старый принцип "разделяй и властвуй" никто не отменял).